# i cant fetch the scholarships data according to my conditions from mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, flask

```
@app.route('/search_scholarships', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_scholarships():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get user input for conditions
        Category = request.form.get('Category')
        Marks = request.form.get('Marks')
        State = request.form.get('State')
        Qualification = request.form.get('Qualification')

        # Check if the input is None or empty and provide a default value (e.g., 0)
        Marks = int(Marks) if Marks and Marks.isdigit() else 0
        Qualification = int(Qualification) if Qualification and Qualification.isdigit() else 0

        # Define the search conditions based on user input
        search_conditions = {
            'Category': Category,
            'Marks': {'$lte': Marks},
            'State': State,
            'Qualification': {'$lte': Qualification}
        }

        # Execute the MongoDB query
        scholarships_data = list(scholarships.find(search_conditions))
        print("Scholarships data:", scholarships_data)

        return render_template('results.html', results=scholarships_data)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scholarship Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Scholarship Search</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/search_scholarships">
        <label for="category">Category:</label>
        <input type="text" name="category" required>
        <br>
        <label for="marks">Marks:</label>
        <input type="text" name="marks" required>
        <br>
        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" name="state" required>
        <br>
        <label for="qualification">Qualification:</label>
        <input type="text" name="qualification" required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search Scholarships">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my search template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scholarship Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Scholarship Search Results</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Caste</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Qualification</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for result in results %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ result.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ result.Category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ result.Caste }}</td>
                    <td>{{ result.Gender }}</td>
                    <td>{{ result.State }}</td>


                    <td>{{ result.Qualification }}</td>
                    <td>{{ result.Marks }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my results template where the scholarships are displayed, which is not displaying

i used monogdb compass for database and i m using flask and when i search for the scholarships with some conditions as given in the code it doesn't display anything, can anyone explain? `your text`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using lowercase field names in your form while the name of the fields in your data are in uppercase ?

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="/search_scholarships">
    <label for="category">Category:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Category" required>
    <br>
    <label for="marks">Marks:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Marks" required>
    <br>
    <label for="state">State:</label>
    <input type="text" name="State" required>
    <br>
    <label for="qualification">Qualification:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Qualification" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search Scholarships">
</form>
```